# Database access Problems with Django and MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions, django

I've got Apache and `mod_wsgi` up and running, and am now trying to introduce Django to MySQL.

I've created a database named 'django' and a 'django' user; and I've granted all to django on django:

```
grant ALL on django.* to 'django'@'localhost';
```

Django's settings.py has been configured with MySQL's settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'django': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'django': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        '<a password>': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        '': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        '': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

However when I try to run syncdb (`python manage.py syncdb`) I get:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 102, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 338, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 250, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 322, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'ec2-user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

The last line has me baffled.  I'm not sure why it's trying to connect as `ec2-user` instead of `Django`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, I'm not certain why it would default to ec2-user, (unless that happens to be the owner of the process which is running Django), but that config file is far from standard. I believe you want:

```
default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME':'django',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER':'django',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD':'<a password>',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
```

It looked like originally, instead of replacing the "NAME" value, you replaced the "NAME" key (and the same for all of the other keys in the dict).

Comment: Thanks so much.  In looking at the config file I don't even know where my brain was at.  I remember thinking '' : '' looks odd.